# Send only few properties of objects within an Array in ajax call with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
// Initialize the object, before adding data to it.
var NewPerson = new Object();

NewPerson.FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
NewPerson.LastName = $("#LastName").val();
NewPerson.Address = $("#Address").val();
NewPerson.City = $("#City").val();
NewPerson.State = $("#State").val();
NewPerson.Zip = $("#Zip").val();
```

In actual I'm populating and sending an array of NewPerson objects. I'm using all the properties in my javascript but when I make ajax call like below, I want to only send two of the properties say for `FirstName` and `LastName`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "PersonService.asmx/AddPerson",
  data: "{'NewPerson':" + JSON.stringify(NewPerson) + "}",
  dataType: "json"
});
```

**NOTE:** I'm using an array not a single object of `NewPerson`. The above code is just for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write a function to achieve that:

```
function extractMembers(arr, members)
{
    var m, o, i, j;
    var output = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        o = {};
        for (j = 0; j < members.length; ++j) {
            m = members[j];
            o[m] = arr[i][m];
        }
        output.push(o);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Now you can use the function like this:

```
var objects = [{FirstName: "...", LastName: "...", Address: "..."},
               {FirstName: "...", LastName: "...", Address: "..."}]

var toSend = extractMembers(objects, ["FirstName", "LastName"]);
```

One more thing: You might want to use the short-notation to create objects in JavaScript:

```
var NewPerson = {
    FirstName: $("#FirstName").val(),
    LastName: $("#LastName").val(),
    ...
};
```

Comment: @Ferdinand, that last example will not work. You need to use strings as keys.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: That is not true.... you confuse this with valid JSON where the keys indeed have to be double quoted strings.

Comment: Can anyone please explain me properly what point @Jacob has raised? I didn't understood it.

Comment: Getting something now. But when we do stringify does it give keys as strings?

Comment: Thank you very much @Ferdinand also for that extra tip.

Comment: @Ismail: Yes, if you apply `JSON.stringify`, it converts all keys and values into valid JSON. JSON and the literal object notation are quite similar, but only *quite* ;) (JSON has its limitations). You can read more about the syntax of JSON at http://json.org/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, you can't tell `JSON.stringify` which propertys of an object/array you want to parse and which not. If you really need to create the `NewPerson` object "manually", you have to filter the values which you want to send yourself.

A better approach seems to be the method `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()`. Both will read 
`input` elements from a `form` element, but only those, which own a `name=` property. So you could just give #FirstName and #LastName a name property.

Reference: [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Thanks @jAndy for the answer. The assignment of values in the NewPerson object is dummy. In actual there is lot more in my code. Appreciate that you just didn't tried to answer the question rather looked at the bigger problem to solve it. Thanks again.